# Calculating area with Europe Albers Equal Area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to calculate the area for a number of polygons in EPSG:102013, having changed it from EPSG:3857. When using the field calculator $area, the entire column was returned as nan. Has the transformation to 102013 not worked properly and if so, how can I force the data into 102013?

Comment: You should explain how you changed the CRS. `Set CRS for Layer` is not the right step, but rather `Save As ...`.

Comment: Thank you, I have a much more likely number for my areas now